# how to align the record in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I really want the data in my database to be in the same row.
My problem is that when I submit the start time the end time automatically becomes like this: `00:00:00`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//Connect and select a database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "" )or die("cannot connect to database server");
mysql_select_db("dbdorm")or die("cannot select the database");

//if form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
          date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
            $query = "INSERT INTO datetime (starttime) VALUES(NOW())";
            $submit = mysql_query($query) or die("insertion error");
            header("location:loggedin.php?");
        }
        else{
          date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');


            $query = "INSERT INTO datetime (endtime) VALUES(NOW())";
            $submit2 = mysql_query($query) or die("insertion error");
            header("location:loggedin.php?");
          }

?>
```

Comment: What is the data type for starttime and endtime fields in MySQL ?

Comment: You would need to use an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT` on the second go around.

Comment: If you do an INSERT, you automatically create a new row in the database. If you want to set the endtime of a previous row, use `UPDATE datetime SET endtime = NOW()` (this will update the endtime in every row in the datetime table, if you want to update a specific row, you will need to use `WHERE` with a selection statement). Here is the specification for UPDATE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: starttime is datetime and endtime is time